# Converting crypto to crypto-js script (AES-256-CFB)

Tags: javascript, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

Can you help me convert this script (node js crypto module ) to crypto-js. I've searched but haven't found a solution.

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
const encryptionKey = "8U8BKkTTyVLRy2ovQgAkRvqSgKLwz2Sg"
const message_to_encrypt = '123456'

const EncryptBase64AES = (text) => {
    const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16)
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cfb', encryptionKey, iv)
    let encrypted = [iv, cipher.update(text, 'utf8')];
    encrypted.push(cipher.final());
    return Buffer.concat(encrypted).toString('base64url');
}

const DecryptBase64AES = (encrypted) => {
    const contents = Buffer.from(encrypted, 'base64url');
    const iv = contents.subarray(0,16)
    const textBytes = contents.subarray(16);
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cfb', encryptionKey, iv)
    let res = decipher.update(textBytes, '', 'utf8');
    res += decipher.final('utf8');
    return res;
}

console.log(EncryptBase64AES(message_to_encrypt))
console.log(DecryptBase64AES(EncryptBase64AES(message_to_encrypt)))
```

I have used this script (crypto for encrypting) and crypto-js for decrypting, but cannot decrypting

```
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js')
const crypto = require('crypto')
const CRYPTO_IV_LENGTH = 16
const encryptionKey = "8U8BKkTTyVLRy2ovQgAkRvqSgKLwz2Sg"
const message_to_encrypt = '123456'

const EncryptBase64AES2 = (text) => {
    const iv  = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
    const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(encryptionKey), {
        iv:iv, 
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CFB, 
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    })
    return CryptoJS.enc.Base64url.stringify(encrypted.ciphertext)
}

const DecryptBase64AES2 = (encrypted) => {
    const contents = Buffer.from(encrypted, 'base64url');
    const iv = contents.subarray(0,16)
    const textBytes = contents.subarray(16);
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cfb', encryptionKey, iv)
    let res = decipher.update(textBytes, '', 'utf8');
    res += decipher.final('utf8');
    return res;
}

console.log(EncryptBase64AES2(message_to_encrypt))
console.log(DecryptBase64AES2(EncryptBase64AES2(message_to_encrypt)))
```

Comment: i looked the documentation of NodeJS version to find the padding used but couldn't, doesn't seem to specify,  https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptocreatecipherivalgorithm-key-iv-options

Comment: For the CryptoJS-encryption to be functionally equivalent to the crypto-encryption, IV and ciphertext must be concatenated in the CryptoJS code: `return CryptoJS.enc.Base64url.stringify(iv.concat(encrypted.ciphertext))` and padding must be disabled: `padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding`.

Comment: Thank you bro MZM, @Topaco, case closed & solved